# SSIS export to cell in Excel template

Tags: ssis

Trying to use SSIS to extract 3 integers from one sql server table, and put them in an Excel Template in cells B4, B5, and B6. In the Excel Destination Editor, I've tried Insert into, Update, and mapping to F1, F2 etc...What do you think would be the best approach

Answer (score 0):

In my view you have two options.  If you are using out of the box excel destination in ssis , add headings for B4, B5, and B6 in first row in excel. Then map the source to these headings.
Or
Buy CozyRoc excel destination. It's excel destination lets you specify a starting column and row indexs.